# Css scale div from 0.1 to 1?

Tags: css

I know how to scale from 1 to 2:

```
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
```

But I need from 0.1 to 1. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Just set the initial scale value to `0.1`, then transition it to `1`..

Comment: But how to set the initial scale value to 0.1?

Comment: Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/R89Dy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options, using `animation` or `transition`, both will work as anticipated as long as you specify the starting values. `animation` is typically the preferred option when you want more control over the intermediate keyframes, or the immediate application of an animation.

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

### [Using `animation`](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7A5fN/1/)

```
div {
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
    transform: scale(0.1);
    -webkit-animation: transformer 4s ease-in 0s 1;
    animation: transformer 4s ease-in 0s 1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes transformer {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
    }
}
@keyframes transformer {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);
    }
}
```

### [Using `transition`](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/7A5fN/2/)

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
}
```

Comment: @JohnyFree - glad you got a solution :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify `transform: scale(0.1);` on the element (don't forget vendor prefixes) before you scale it to 1.

See the example below:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/GaAw4/)**

*CSS:*

```
div{
    width:500px; 
    height:500px;
    background:gold;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
    transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.1);
}
div:hover{
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
    transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
}
```

Comment: Tnx but rotate is not working when scale(0.1) is added like that.

Comment: @JohnyFree sorry about that, it's fixed now